# Are private variables in Objective-C strong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, private-members

So searching around Stack Overflow this seems to be how to make private variables in Objective-C:

```
@interface ClassName()
{
@private
    NSArray* private;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* public;
@end
```

Now this is where I get confused. The property is declared as `(strong, nonatomic)`, but the private variable has nothing of the sort. So how does arc know if it's strong or not?

Comment: FYI - The code you posted is the old way of doing things. Private ivars now belong in the `@implementation` block in the .m file. Also, there is no need to declare ivars for properties. And there is no need to have an explicit `@synthesize` call. Simply declare the `@property` in the .h and you are done. The compiler will automatically synthesize an ivar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of a property, the ownership of the associated instance variable is implied by the ownership of the property:

See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html:

> If a property is synthesized, then the associated instance variable is
>   the instance variable which is named, possibly implicitly, by the
>   @synthesize declaration. If the associated instance variable already
>   exists, then its ownership qualification must equal the ownership of
>   the property; otherwise, the instance variable is created with that
>   ownership qualification.

Generally, Objective-C objects are by default strong:

> If an object is declared with retainable object owner type, but
>   without an explicit ownership qualifier, its type is implicitly
>   adjusted to have __strong qualification.

Note that since the LLVM 4.0 compiler (Xcode 4.4), the `@synthesize` statement and the associated instance variable is created automatically, so you need only to declare the property.

Answer (score 13):

Instance variables are `__strong` by default.

From [Apple's ARC Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), regarding variables (presumed to include instance variables):

> __strong is the default

and later:

> With ARC, instance variables are strong references by default—assigning an object to an instance variable directly does extend the lifetime of the object

This holds until the property is connected to the ivar via `@synthesize`. At this point, the ownership qualifier of the property takes precedence. However, if you declare a property as anything but strong, and then implement both the setters and getters by hand, you'll have to manually declare the backing ivar's ownership qualifier as well.

Answer (score 3):

The qualifiers on `@property` specify the behavior of the synthesized setter and other ARC inserted code.  Variables themselves aren't really strong or not, they're just memory locations.  So you've got it coded strong right now.

The way to make it private (and strong) is to declare it strong in a category inside .m file.

```
// .h
// nothing

// .m
@interface ClassName()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* myStrongPrivateProperty;
@end

// that's it
```

Comment: *"Variables themselves aren't really strong or not, they're just memory locations."* - This is wrong. All Objective-C objects have an ownership which is by default __strong.

Comment: It's metaphorical.  That quote states a convention about how to treat those memory locations.  Instance variables are bytes in a struct ultimately, they aren't stored with extra bits explaining how they should be treated at runtime.  That's a compiler table.

Comment: This is somewhat like saying "Instance variables are not typed, they're just bits in a struct." The fact that a variable is represented by bits does not change te fact that semantically, it has other attributes as well. Variables can be __strong or _weak, whether or not a `@property` exists.

Comment: +1 for the true point and the good analogy.  These things are decided by convention (like we could make one up that says unadorned 4 bytes shall be treated as ints).  My read on the OP question was from where do the ARC semantic's come?  They come from the @property declaration whether or not you've declared the struct explicitly.

Comment: +1 for the instruction how to declare a private property correctly.